# Intel 8086 Assembly Multiplication

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos

I need to multiply the value of Al (after 48 is subtracted) by 10, but as my code is now it is multiplying Al by Al. Not sure how to fix it so it multiplies the value of (N1[0]- 48) * 10

```
            mov     BX, 0
            mov     AH, 00h
            mov     Al, N1[BX]   ; Get a character
            Sub Al, 48 ; to get decimel value from character 
            Mov Bx, 10 
            Mul Al
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `mul` instruction? Have a close look at it. HINT: where does `bx` occur in your `mul` instruction as you have it?

Comment: So I should mul bx not Al

Comment: @L315 That should be better.

Comment: It's not a guessing game. Read the documentation for `mul`.

Comment: @lurker where is the documentation?

Comment: Searching for the instruction mnemonic and "x86" will turn up the documentation 9 times out of 10. In this case: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html. The canonical reference is, of course, Intel's manuals. See links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: Note also that `xor reg, reg` is the normal way of setting a register to 0 because it is more efficient. Even if you don't write it that way, you should get used to seeing it written that way so you can understand other people's code. And I would suggest that you start writing it that way yourself. Otherwise, you have already solved the problem: `mul` multiplies al/ax/eax by its operand, so this should be `mul bx`. Voting to close as a simple typo.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray